# Как проверить и остановить, при определенном условии, AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем нужно делаю проверку формы, Сделал средствами JS и средствами PHP Вопрос как можно получить ответ от сервера, и если ответ не годится то предложить заполнить нужное поле. А то я что то не пойму.

По локальному Event succes можно принять ответ от сервера. Но тут же остановить скрипт нельзя.

```
success:(function(data){
                    if(data.uname===1) {
                            $('#inputregName').css('border', '');
                            }
                            else{
                                $('#inputregName').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                            }})
```

Comment: Что значит тут же остановить скрипт нельзя? В `success` добавь условие прежде чем манипулировать с ответом сервера.

Comment: @ Razmik Galstyan Дело в том что я жду от сервера ответ что поле факапное, Если ответ плохой то нужно вернуться к форме.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function(data){
      if (data.uname === 1) {
        $('#inputregName').css('border', '');
        $("form")[0].submit(); // если надо
      } else {
        $('#inputregName').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
      }   
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```